# How i get all the software in Ubuntu software download?

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center

How i get all the software in Ubuntu software download ?
there is a txt list or a website with categorize that i can navigate easily
and see all the applications that is in Ubuntu download software ?

thanks for all.

Comment: Is the software-center not good enough? It is categorized and has a rating system. See here: http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/ubuntu-software-centre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A website containing all official packages (but not from the partner repository) is http://packages.ubuntu.com/

You can:

- browse packages per release and section
- search by name and description
- search for filenames inside the packages

Some features:

- You can get a list of files inside a package
- A download link to the package file is available
- You can get the changelog for the package
- Links to the bug tracker and project home page
- A list of similar packages

Comment: Thx you! that what i an looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Software Center](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareCenterFAQ) has all the categories and it is nicely organized. It comes with Ubuntu. If you are using Unity then it should be in the launcher to the left. If not, click the "Applications" menu on the top left and select "Ubuntu Software Center."